# Displaying date as X axis in graph view not working (displaying the same everytime)

Tags: java, android, graph, android-graphview

I am trying to create a graph in graphview that displays on the x-axis dates and on the y-axis an integer. The data are stored in an sqlite database. Here is my `DatabaseHelper.java` file:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="records.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="records_table";
    public static final String COL_1="date";
    public static final String COL_2="percentage";

    public DatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(date DATE,percentage INTEGER)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void insertData(Integer percentage){
        SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd");
        Date date = new Date();
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put("date", dateFormat.format(date));
        initialValues.put("percentage",percentage);
        long rowId = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, initialValues);

    }
}
```

And here is the file where the graph is displayed, `Statistics.java` :

```
public class Statistics extends AppCompatActivity {
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    GraphView graphView;
    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>(new DataPoint[0]);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd");



    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_statistics);
        graphView= (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
        graphView.addSeries(series);
        graphView.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(new DefaultLabelFormatter(){
            @Override
            public String formatLabel(double value,boolean isValueX){
                if (isValueX){
                    return sdf.format(new Date((long) value));
                } else {
                    return super.formatLabel(value,isValueX);
                }
            }
        });
        series.resetData(getDataPoint());
        exqInsert();
    }

    private void exqInsert() {
        series.resetData(getDataPoint());
        graphView.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(new DefaultLabelFormatter(){
            @Override
            public String formatLabel(double value,boolean isValueX){
                if (isValueX){
                    return sdf.format(new Date((long) value));
                } else {
                    return super.formatLabel(value,isValueX);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    private DataPoint[] getDataPoint() {
        String[] columns= {"date","percentage"};
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("records.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
        Cursor cursor=db.query("records_table",columns,null,null,null,null,null);
        DataPoint[] dp=new DataPoint[cursor.getCount()];

        for (int i=0 ; i<cursor.getCount(); i++){
            cursor.moveToNext();
            dp[i]= new DataPoint(cursor.getLong(0),cursor.getInt(1));
        }

        return dp;
    }

}
```

The Data on my records.db database are the following:

[image]

But the graph I get is this:

[image]

What Am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the lable formatter used to show currencies as below:

> graphView.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(new DefaultLabelFormatter()

I suggest try using this label formatter for date as XAxis

```
graphView
.getGridLabelRenderer()
.setLabelFormatter(new DateAsXAxisLabelFormatter(GraphActivity.this, new SimpleDateFormat(getResources().getString(R.string.graph_date_format))));
```

Comment: @thriteenchess this is just an example, if you think you don't need then use you own implementation.